# Error while creating a new class in xtend eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt, xtend

Error while creating a new xtend class in xtend.

[image]

Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers
Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Eclipse Xtend:  Xtend IDE   2.14.0.v20180523-0530

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: Your Eclipse is two releases behind and Xtend is even older which might be the cause for this issue.

Comment: @howlger thanks for reply. Will upgrade xtend version to the latest.

Comment: Upgrade also the Eclipse IDE, not only Xtend. There is a reason why there is a simultaneous release. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades

Comment: @howlger Thanks, Will Upgrade both.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for reply, I did see logs logged in .log file of workspace directory .metadata after 30 minutes also for that error. Will upgrade the eclipse and xtend version.

Comment: @howlger Thanks, upgrading both eclipse and xtend resolved the issue. I have posted in the answer section if someone faces a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Eclipse and xtend to latest version resolved the issue.

See question comments from howlger for reference.

[Upgrade Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades)